# Adding a final logger to a inner static class.. how to?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I have an inner class and i would like to add a logger, currently its being adding it via the constructor.

my outer class (spring bean) has the following:

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

my inner class has the following:

```
private final static class car {

    final Logger LOGGER;

    public car(Logger LOGGER) {
     this.LOGGER = LOGGER;
    }

}
```

I dont like the above is there any other way to work this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger (getClass ());

    private static class Bar
    {
        private final Logger logger = Foo.this.logger;
    }
}
```

but better way would probably be to do:

```
public class Foo
{
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger (Foo.class);

    private static class Bar
    {
        private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger (Bar.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for following the best standards. @user1555190 Your logger should ALWAYS reflect the class it's logging from. Otherwise, you'll be logging from class "Bar" but your output will say "Foo".

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private final static class Car {
   void drive() {
       LOGGER.debug(msg);
   }
}
```

or

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private final static class Car {
        private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Car.class);

        void drive() {
            LOGGER.debug(msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the same logger that was handed to the outer class, if sharing is your intention:

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OuterClass.class);
```